# Retrieve attributes of child from Firebase to android app using ValueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Structure of my database:

[image]

I want to retrieve all the details (calories,carbohydrates,fat,protein) in a Textview when the key such as "Apple" or "Orange" are entered in an Plaintext field.

This is the code I'm using to retrieve data but my app keeps crashing when I rn it:

```
    bdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(Diet.this, "here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            final String food_item = etfooditem.getText().toString().trim();
            Toast.makeText(Diet.this, food_item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  databasesReference.addValueEventListener(new com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          for (com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.child("Food_Databse").getChildren()) {
              Getters getter;
              getter = (Getters) ds.getValue();
              if (food_item == getter.getName()) {

                  String abc = getter.getCal();
                  Toast.makeText(Diet.this, abc, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  break;
              }else{
                  Toast.makeText(Diet.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
              //getter.getCarb();
              //getter.getFat();
              //getter.getPro();
          }
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

      }
  });

        }


    });
```

Comment: What is getters?

Comment: Post your logcat

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve your problem, please use this code:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
String fruit = editText.getText().toString();

DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference fruitRef = rootRef.child("Food-Databse").child(fruit);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String calories = ds.child("Calories").getValue(String.class);
            String carbohydrates = ds.child("Carbohydrates").getValue(String.class);
            String fat = ds.child("Fat").getValue(String.class);
            String protein = ds.child("Protein").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d("TAG", calories + " / " + carbohydrates + " / " + fat + " / " + protein);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
fruitRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Be careful that i used `Food-Databse` as i see in your screen shot and not `Food-Database` as it normally would be.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

first i would recommend adding a name field additional to the key

```
Query foodsQuery = database.getReference("Food_Databse");
foodsQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Food food = postSnapshot.getValue(Food.class);
                //don't need it if you add name child field (see comment in class)
                food.name = postSnapshot.getKey();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    }
);
```

you may want to create a Food class (in a separate file!!)

```
public class Food {
    String name = "";
    int calories;
    int carbohydrates;
    int fat;
    int protein;

    public Food() {
    }

    /*
    //uncomment iff you add name child field in database
    public int getName() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setName(String val) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    */
    public int getCalories() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setCalories(int val) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getCarbohydrates() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setCarbohydrates(int val) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getFat() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setFat(int val) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getProtein() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setProtein(int val) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

instead of using the Food class you can use

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = (HashMap<String, Object>)postSnapshot.getValue()
```

or if all values are integers:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = (HashMap<String, Integer>)postSnapshot.getValue()
```